# Dynamically allocated data members in class constructor

Tags: c++

I am having issues with trying to figure out how I would turn a data member inside a class (which was originally an int) into a pointer to a dynamically allocated piece of memory.

I know I can do int *num = new int under normal circumstances, but how would I initialize it in a class?

My teacher did an amazing job of not explaining this in the crappiest way possible in class -_-.

This is an example of the class and the constructor.

The header

```
class Double
{
private:
double *val;
```

The .cpp

```
Double::Double()
{
this->equals(0.0);
}

Double::Double(const Double &d)
{
this->equals(d.val);
}

Double::Double(const double &d)
{
this->equals(d);
}

Double::Double(const Interger &i)
{
this->equals(i.toInt());
}

//New overloaded constructor using strings
Double::Double(const string &s)
{
this->equals(s);
}

void Double::equals(const double &d)
{
this->val = d;
}
```

All I know is I have to make the data member a pointer now, but I have no idea how to create the new memory.  I tried looking this up but I could not find an example of how to do DAM inside an actual class for its memory and constructor.

*EDIT*
Solution was a simpler then I thought.

Double::Double() : val(new double)
{
......
}

just have to do that to every constructor, then change any instance of d.val or this->val to *d.val or *this->val.

Comment: `Double::Double() : val(new double) {...}` And in `equals`, `*val = d;`. You would also need to write a destructor, and write (or suppress) a copy constructor and copy assignment operator. Why exactly does `val` need to be a pointer?

Comment: Because this week is how to use DAM, and since the professor likes to continue using the previous weeks lab and val is the only data member in the class, it is what we are turning into dynamic memory instead of just writing a new program to practice it.

I can point out I know how to do this in a function, or in main, just didnt know how to create it in the class.  Classes keep kicking my ass...

Comment: Did I mention he hasnt even taught us deconstructors yet so the code is supposted to never release the memory...

Comment: Tutorials like http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/  should help you understand dynamic memory allocation.  Doing it inside a class is no different from doing it outside.  You use the `new` operator as always, and store its output as `this->val`.  The assignment line (i.e. the body of `Double::equals`) will have to change—but I assume figuring out how is part of the exercise.

Comment: I think its the whole dealing with this-> that ends up giving me so much headache, trying to figure out if i just type this->val, *this->val, or this->*val, etc.

For instance I only got the error in the this->equals(d.val); to shut up when I typed this->equals(*d.val);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM (So the problem is solved)

Solution was simpler then I thought.

```
Double::Double() : val(new double)
{
......
}
```

just have to do that to every constructor, then change any instance of d.val or this->val to *d.val or *this->val.

Deconstructors will have to be created to clear the memory though.